# Resizing and positioning RecyclerView items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, grid-layout, recyclerview-layout, gridlayoutmanager

I am using RecyclerView to show items in Grid layout.
Below is the image of emulator and the desire results i need to achieve.
Left side (executing) image is the output on my emulator, while Right Side (Desired) is the output i want to achieve.

**Activity Layout XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#d3c3c3">

 <include
    android:id="@+id/toolBarIncluded"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_new_layout" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolBarIncluded"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:id="@+id/recyclerAdView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.65"
        android:background="#009688" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recyclerAdView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.35"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:gravity="center">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

            android:id="@+id/recyclerGridView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:foregroundGravity="center" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**List Item XML**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/llGridItemLayout"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:layout_margin="6dp"
 android:background="@drawable/drawable_grid_item_background"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:paddingStart="2dp"
 android:paddingEnd="2dp"
 android:orientation="vertical">

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivItemIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_new_receipt_wrong" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvItemName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lines="1"
    android:text="My Complaints"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

**Activity Code Snippet**

```
    gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 3);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(demoDashAdapter);
```

**Adapter Code Snippet**

```
int viewHeight ,viewWidth ;
public onCreateViewHolder(){
   viewHeight = viewGroup.getMeasuredHeight() / 4;
   viewWidth = viewGroup.getMeasuredWidth() / 3;
  ...
}

public onBindViewHolder(){

  viewHolder.itemLayout.setMinimumWidth(viewWidth);
  viewHolder.itemLayout.setMinimumHeight(viewHeight);
  ...
}
```

[image]
Hence my question here is, how can i dynamically resize the items in the recyclerView. Please note that i am using layout weight as 0.65 and 0.35 against the weightSum 1;

please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why `viewHeight = viewGroup.getMeasuredHeight() / 4`?

if you want to display 3 rows just divide by `3`.
Take also into account margins that you have inside your `item.xml`

So getting height for each item in a row should be something like:

```
(viewGroup.getMeasuredHeight()/3) - (marginTop + marginBot)
```

Comment: When Dividing by 3 the recycler view items are expanding more in height and recyclerview turning into scrollable.

Comment: that is probably because of margin that you have to take also in count:
Maybe try something like (viewGroup.getMeasuredHeight()/3) - (marginTop + marginBot), but as mentioned by @Pawel, LayoutManager should be responsible for that.

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: (viewGroup.getMeasuredHeight()/3) - (marginTop + marginBot)
Worked for me.

please post as an answer.

Comment: @java bee I have fixed my post to include the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `RecyclerView.Adapter` to alter how the views are laid out. This is responsibility of `RecyclerView.LayoutManager`.

You can override method validating `View.LayoutParams` to evenly distribute size:

```
 //customized GridLayoutManager
 gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 3){
     @Override
     public boolean checkLayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp) {
         // force size of viewHolder here, this will override layout_height and layout_width from xml
         lp.height = getHeight() / getSpanCount();
         lp.width = getWidth() / getSpanCount();
         return true;
     }
 };
 recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

Comment: this worked too, i had too add the calculations given by @Nimdokai

Comment: nice and clean answer +1

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `LayoutParams` for this inside your `onCreateViewHolder`, something like this:

```
  public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View rowLayout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = rowLayout.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = (int) (parent.getHeight() * 0.15); // control the recyclerView row height from here
    rowLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    return new Holder(rowLayout);
}
```